# what is the better way to position two elements in a container using CSS? (one on the left and one on the right of its container)

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

I have some stupid CSS doubts about how to position two elements (two div that implements colored boxes) in a container using CSS.

Look at this test page made by me: http://onofri.org/example/Typo3Test/mycontent/

In the center area of this website I have put some content (some colored boxes) and its code is:

**HTML/CSS code:**

```css
#header2 {
  background-color: #DEB887;
}
#container {
  /* consente di posizionare un elemento al centro del suo contenitore */
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  /* Imposto la larghezza */
}
#first {
  /*background-color: #8FBC8F;*/
  /* SFUMATURA BACKGROUND: */
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #35F2EC 0%, #16B7D6 50%, #016D94 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #35F2EC 0%, #16B7D6 50%, #016D94 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #35F2EC 0%, #16B7D6 50%, #016D94 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #35F2EC), color-stop(0.5, #16B7D6), color-stop(1, #016D94));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #35F2EC 0%, #16B7D6 50%, #016D94 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #35F2EC 0%, #16B7D6 50%, #016D94 100%);
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  float: left;
  /*margin-right: 15px;*/
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-shadow: 6px 7px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
  -moz-box-shadow: 6px 7px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 7px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
}
#second {
  background-color: #8FBC8F;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  float: right;
  /*margin-left: 15px;*/
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-shadow: 6px 7px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
  -moz-box-shadow: 6px 7px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 7px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header2">
    <p>TITLE</p>
  </div>

  <div id="first">
    <p>BLA BLA BLA</p>
    <p>BLA BLA BLA</p>
    <p>BLA BLA BLA</p>
  </div>

  <div id="second">
    <p>BLA BLA BLA</p>
    <p>BLA BLA BLA</p>
    <p>BLA BLA BLA</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

As you can see there is an external `#container` that contains and `#header2` div and under this div there are two columns created by `first` and `second` div.

I want that the `first` column is placed within on the left of the `#container` div and that `second` column is placed within on the right of the `#container` div.

To do this thing I have set the `float: left` property to the `#first` column and the `float: right` property to the `#second` column.

Is it a good solution or can create some kind of problem?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think there wont be any problem ..this can be also achieved in may other ways

- you can also use `div.wrap` to wrap `#first & #second` then you could use `display:inline-block;` in `#first & #second` while `display:inline;` in `div.wrap` and also see **[should you use inline-block as a substitute of float](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/inline-blocks/)** and also **[float vs inline-block](http://www.ternstyle.us/blog/float-vs-inline-block)**
- you could use `float:left;` only in `#first` then `#second` would inherit it.it will give you side by side contents
- you can also use `display:table-row;` for `div.wrap` and `display:table-cell;` for `#first & #second`.but its better to avoid

Answer (score 1):

My favorite is to use flex, as in this example:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #DDDDAA;
}

#col1, #col2 {
  width: 35%;
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #DDDDFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="col1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
  <div id="col2">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
</div>
```